# Convert version in format major.minor.build.patch to integer

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do I convert a string which is holding a version in this format `55.2.2883.95` to integer? I am working on modifying open source Omaha server and it stores the input version number as big int type in PostgresSQL. For example, if the input version string is `55.2.2883.95` then it's corresponding value in the db is stored as `60481918402655`.

Thanks

Comment: And how does `'55.2.2883.95'` turn into `60481918402655`?

Comment: what is the largest number of minor/major/release version, and is there any limit  (or reasonable assumption) at all?

Comment: @Marat: 8, 8, 16, 16 bits

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That's how Omaha server is storing those data, not me

Comment: I'm 90% sure this a dupe, but I don't have time to go dupe hunting right now.

Comment: @leaf no it's not

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You should look at the answer, that should answer your question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming there always 4 numbers in version, we can use bitshift to store these numbers in different parts of the int:

```
chunks = [int(c) for c in version.split(".")]
return (chunks[0] << 40) + (chunks[1] << 32) + (chunks[2] << 16) + chunks[3]
```

Test:

```
>>> version = '55.2.2883.95'
>>> (chunks[0] << 40) + (chunks[1] << 32) + (chunks[2] << 16) + chunks[3]
60481918402655
```

Comment: The output doesn't match. For input '55.2.2883.95' am getting a very long integer. Thanks

Comment: I missed parenthesis in the initial answer. Please recheck with the updated version

Comment: Yes, I was about to let you know that you missed parenthesis cause I just inserted parenthesis and it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you won't mind can you please let me know how you found out the exact numbers to left shift those chunks with? Your response was fast too.

Comment: the last chunk (95) has zero shift and it is at most 16 bits long. It means that we need to move the last but one chunk (2883) by 16 bits: `(chunks[2] << 16)`. The next chunk should be shifted by 16+16=32 bits: `(chunks[1] << 32)`. Likely, the very first one should be shifted by 16+16+8 = 40 bits: `(chunks[0] << 40)`